# Proof linear independency lemma

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, vector-spaces

If $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ is in the complex vector space $V$ and $\mathbf{w}_1 = \mathbf{u} + i \mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{w}_2 = \mathbf{u} - i \mathbf{v}$ are linear independent then will the vectors $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ also be linear independent.

How can I proove this lemma?

Comment: Try using $$w_1+iw_2 = (u+v)+i(u+v) $$

Answer (score 1):

Notice that

$$\frac{\alpha - i\beta}{2} w_1 + \frac{\alpha + i\beta}{2} w_2 = 
\left( \frac{\alpha - i\beta}{2} + \frac{\alpha + i\beta}{2} \right) u + \left( \frac{\alpha - i\beta}{2} - \frac{\alpha + i\beta}{2} \right) iv = \alpha u + \beta v.$$

If you need further hints, please ask in the comments of this answer.